# I have an http error intorceptor in my angular app. I am catching all errors from the backend. How can I display all the errors?

Tags: angular, error-handling, interceptor

I undertand that I can navigate to the component where I want to display the errors, but how do I actually get the errors out of the interceptor and into the component class.  I know that for components I have to have a property to hold the values of my objects in order to display them, and for those I have get, post, put, update, or delete methods going to the backend to get the response from.  I am very new to this and just trying to learn the best practices, the advice I was given was to put a router.navigate in my client side catch block that redirects the user to the component with a custom message, which I understand how to do that but for testing purposing I want to actually display the custom error messages at the backend in my api.  Do I have to create a service to get those or can I just get them out of the interceptor?  I would appreciate any assistance or help I can get with this.Thanks in advance.

```
import {
          HttpEvent,
          HttpHandler,
          HttpRequest,
          HttpErrorResponse,
          HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ErrorIntercept implements HttpInterceptor {
   intercept(
     request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
     ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
           retry(1),
              catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                let errorMessage = '';
                  if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                    //Client side error
                  errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
                  router.navigate('/login');

                   } else {
                    //server side error
                     errorMessage = `Error Status: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
                                   router.navigate('/login');

                          }
                     console.log(errorMessage);
                     return throwError(errorMessage);
                          })
                    )
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi just use any alert message service which you can hit from any part of the application and it will be display as a toast message in your application.

I have also Implemented this using **ngx-toastr** its an npm package just install and call its service

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
      if (err.status === 401) {
        // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
        this.authenticationService.LogoutUser();
        location.reload(true);
      }
      this.toastr.error(AppMessages.SOME_THING_WENT_WRONG);
      // this.alertService.error('Something went wrong');
      const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
      this.GetSetLogForServer(err);
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }
```